# Getting devices on .NET without using WMI

Tags: .net, windows, networking, device, nic

How can I get a device group or the network devices that shows the Device Manager window without WMI? I tried with devcon but returns all nics.

For example, devcon returns:

[image]

and I just want these one (without the show hidden devices option)

[image]

Any kind of solution for devcon or net framework 2, idea or workaround will be treated as solution if its works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To list the network adapters you can use the [`GetAdaptersInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365917%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WinAPi function, since you are using .Net try the [PInvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/iphlpapi.getadaptersinfo) page for a sample.

Answer (score 1):

Try [System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getallnetworkinterfaces). It returns a collection of all detected network interfaces. You can then filter it down to the interfaces whose operational status is "Up", and/or that have valid IP interface properties (such as a defined IPv4/IPv6 address)

Comment: Only show the interfaces enabled. It returns all nics from image except the DW1520 because is disabled, but present on hardware.